# How to enable downloading in my web view app. This is my code

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Now I have some files that a user can download from the website using webview when I click on the file their is no response and download doesn't begins. 
Similarly I can't upload files using the webview.

How can i enable download on webview so that I can get my files downloaded via this app.

**MyAppWebViewClient.java**

```
 package xyz.hamsterwheelengineer.www.minutenotes;    

 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.webkit.WebView;
 import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
 import android.webkit.DownloadListener;


 public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
 @Override
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

 if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith(("hamsterwheelengineer.xyz"))) {
 return false;
    }

    if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith(("google.com"))) {
        return false;
    }


    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    return true;
  }
 }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package xyz.hamsterwheelengineer.www.minutenotes;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://hamsterwheelengineer.xyz/");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new xyz.hamsterwheelengineer.www.minutenotes.MyAppWebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            //hide loading image
            findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //show webview
            findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }});


}



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    /** Inflating the current activity's menu with res/menu/items.xml */
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    /** Getting the actionprovider associated with the menu item whose id is share */
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.share).getActionProvider();

    /** Setting a share intent */
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

/** Returns a share intent */
private Intent getDefaultShareIntent(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "minuteNotes - Get all of your engineering notes at one place");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT," Visit www.hamsterwheelengineer.xyz or download our minuteNotes app from the playstore to begin.");
    return intent;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add any view in webview if you want to develop full hybrid application like using html,css in webview the you may use phoneGap.
In your case if you want to add an button in webview and on that button click want to download something then my suggestion to you is go for PhoneGap.

```
http://phonegap.com/
```

Comment: I know it can be done in webview via android studio. So will not go for phonegap. Thanks.